# Call the SharePoint REST API from Dynamics record (form)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, dynamics-crm, azure-ad-graph-api

My objective is to call the MS Graph API on form load, then once I have the access token, to then call the SharePoint API to query the members of a particular site group.  I am stuck on CORS implementation (the call works from Postman).  I have added a redirect-uri within my app registration in Azure, but I am still receiving the same error message every time.

Error: Access to fetch at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token' from origin 'https://xxxxx.crm.dynamics.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

[image: JS Code to Call MS Graph API]

[image: Redirect URI in Azure App Registration]

Any insight will be helpful! Please let me know if I should add clarity/details.

Comment: Please include the error you are facing in text/clear snip format

Comment: Sorry about that, didn't realize the picture came out so small.

Comment: Hope this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-proxy/application-proxy-understand-cors-issues) helpful.

Comment: Does this help https://jtuto.com/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-even-though-cors-is-enabled/?

Comment: @Rukmini Hello - I followed the link and when I go to search 'CORS' in Azure Portal, I actually do not get any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was CORS policy. I resolved it by using an async JavaScript call to a Power Automate flow.  The flow natively is allowed in the policy.  Once the flow finishes, it returns a response which the script is waiting for.